# How to detect mobile Safari global orientation rotation animation

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, mobile-safari

Hi I'm trying to trigger an event when mobile Safari rotates to a different orientation. I am aware of the `orientationchange` however this is not acceptable because it is called **after** the orientation rotation animation is played and the new orientation is set. I have an element that I need to hide before or during the animation.

I'm trying to capture the state before the orientation has changed particularly before the animation plays. I've tried applying events like `webkitAnimationStart` and `animationstart` to the `window`, `document` and `document.body` and none of them seem to be triggered. Hoping I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this same problem, did you find one?

Comment: @WassimGr I did not

Comment: I found a partial solution, I'll post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem occurring in almost every mobile browser as far as I saw and there is no straightforward solution for it.

A semi-official suggestion coming from the Chrome team posted [on their blog](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/mobile-web-video-playback) under **Unlock screen on device orientation change** is to use `deviceorientation` and simulate what the browser does internally to figure out the orientation of the device:

```
var previousDeviceOrientation, currentDeviceOrientation;
  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function onDeviceOrientationChange(event) {
    // event.beta represents a front to back motion of the device and
    // event.gamma a left to right motion.
    if (Math.abs(event.gamma) > 10 || Math.abs(event.beta) < 10) {
      previousDeviceOrientation = currentDeviceOrientation;
      currentDeviceOrientation = 'landscape';
      return;
    }
    if (Math.abs(event.gamma) < 10 || Math.abs(event.beta) > 10) {
      previousDeviceOrientation = currentDeviceOrientation;
      // When device is rotated back to portrait, let's unlock screen orientation.
      if (previousDeviceOrientation == 'landscape') {
        screen.orientation.unlock();
        window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', onDeviceOrientationChange);
      }
    }
  });
```

The particular use case the Chrome team used this code for is to get the device's orientation after using `screen.orientation.lock` (which disable orientation change events).

This can be generalized as a substitute for orientation change events giving you a slight time-advantage before the animation kicks in.

The tricky part is figuring out the right angle range for which the browser decides to switch orientations (you don't want to start your animation when the browser doesn't actually switch orientations).

One way to solve this is to take complete control over orientation changes using `screen.orientation.lock` where essentially you set the threshold and lock the orientation accordingly.

However since the world isn't perfect, `screen.orientation.lock` only works in fullscreen mode or in standalone web-apps... If you intend your app to be a fullscreen experience or a standalone web-app then you're in luck.